# Blend modes for overlapping chart series?

Tags: svg, highcharts

Is there a way to mimic Photoshop's layer blend modes with chart content in HighCharts? For instance, I have two area type series that overlap, and instead of setting opacity on the colors I use (with rgba) I would love to have the overlapping areas set to multiply or linear burn. See attached image for example. Another benefit to this is that the gridlines beneath are even more defined under the colored areas.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[redacted]** modern browsers do have some support for blending modes, so this might be possible.

---

The only browser that currently supports SVG blend modes is Opera through filters,
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feBlendElement

Another specification is SVG Compositing:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGCompositing-20090430/#containerElementCompositingOperators
But SVG compositing is not supported by any browser yet.

I don't think VML supports blending modes either, so I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm fairly sure all the svg-capable browsers that support svg filters also support feBlend, see http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/filters-blend-01-b.html.

Comment: Hmmm, the w3 example for filter blends led me to believe it was unsupported (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/filters/feBlend.svg) as it doesn't work in FF or Chrome. I'll have to redact this answer.

Comment: What you see in that example is that the 'BackgroundImage' input isn't well supported.